# How to get the Latitude and Longitude when GPS is not Available?

Tags: android, gps

I have implemented an android application using GoogleApiClient which sends the Location updates after every 5m displacement and it is working fine.

Consider sometimes will not get Gps Signal.In such situation how can we get the update can anyone please help me how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
         Location nwLocation = appLocationService
                        .getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (nwLocation != null) {
                    double latitude = nwLocation.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = nwLocation.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Mobile Location (NW): \nLatitude: " + latitude
                                    + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

the complete tutorial can be found [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-using-gps-network-provider/)

Answer (score 0):

please have a look this [link](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-using-gps-network-provider/).

and i used this code to fetch lat long:

```
public void getCurruntLocation() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}
```

and

```
  private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
            latLng = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(RecentActivity.this,
                    location.getLatitude() + "" + location.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

and simple call `getCurruntLocation()` where you want to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleApiClient uses a LocationRequest class for setting number of parameters. One of them - .setPrioryty. If you are using LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY in some cases googleApiClient won't call onLocationChanged() without gps, due to lack of accuracy of GPRS coordinates.